# Documenting private methods

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is it possible to pull out the documentation for private methods with phpDocumentor?

I realize this wouldn't normally be done, but in my current project it would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -pp option.

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.parseprivate

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. From reading into it, it only shows methods that have a tag @access private, but doesn't show methods that are private

Comment: If --parseprivate is failing to pick up private methods just based on the 'private' keyword in the code, then that's a bug.  @access tags should not be required for PHP5 code.

Comment: @ashnazg & @Charles I tried all sorts of things yesterday with --parseprivate, with no joy, then today I load up and suddenly it is working. Something must have been stuck in a cache somewhere. Thanks for your help.